# Lossless conversion of TIFF to BMP and vice versa in PIL (pillow)

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, tiff, bmp

Now I'm trying to convert the TIFF to BMP and vice versa with pillow fork of PIL.

But the problem is to get the TIFF larger than original one from converted BMP.

I know the TIFF and BMP are using the lossless compression so expected the same result.

Here are codes to show how I converted the TIFF to BMP and vice versa.

- Converts TIFF to BMP

```
img = Image.open(path + '/' + ccittfax_image + '.unknown.tiff')
img.save(ccittfax_image + '.unknown.tiff.bmp')
```

- Converts BMP to TIFF

```
bmp = Image.open(path + '/' + ccittfax_image + '.unknown.tiff.bmp')
bmp.save(ccittfax_image + '.unknown.tiff', format='TIFF', compression='group4', dpi=(1,1))
```

I got the `compression` and `dpi` through `Image.info` attribute in `PIL`.

```
print(img.info)
```

Result:
`{'compression': 'group4', 'dpi': (1, 1), 'resolution': (1, 1)}`

The file size of original TIFF was 1.4kb but result one has 1.5kb.

If I can get the same result, I don't care what method or library is used.

Comment: Is the original TIFF file created with PILLOW as well? Different software may compress the same data slightly different. It's also possible your new file contains other metadata. Use a TIFF tool to find the differences.

Comment: @usr2564301 I extracted the raw data from PDF and added the tiff header.
What TIFF tool do you recommend?